# Prove there exists a natural number $n$ such that $p_1+n(p_2-p_1)$ is prime but $p_2+n(p_2-p_1)$ is not, where $p_1 < p_2$ are primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I am told $n$ should be taken to be the smallest possible n such that $p_2 + n(p_2 - p_1)$ is composite without actually picking a *specific* value for n and then somehow reach a contradiction, but I cannot for the love of god figure out what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ $p_1 + n(p_2 - p_1) = p_2 + (n-1)(p_2 - p_1)$.